# How to find a location on Map from a address which has been input by user?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-maps-mobile

I wanna find the location on Map when using a virtual device (Emulator Android) because i have not a actual device.
Thanks for watching!

Here is my code :

```
enter code herepublic class GoogleMapExample3Activity extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView mapView;
TextView txtView;
LinearLayout zoomControl;
GeoPoint geoPoint;
MapController mapController;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    zoomControl=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomControl);
    View view= mapView.getZoomControls();
    zoomControl.addView(view,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    String address="New York";
    Geocoder geoCoder=new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list;
    try {
        list = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
        Address a=list.get(0);
        Double latitude=a.getLatitude();
        Double longitude=a.getLongitude();
        geoPoint=new GeoPoint( (int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));
        mapController=mapView.getController();
        mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
        mapController.setZoom(18);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    MapController mapController=mapView.getController();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I:
        mapController.zoomIn();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O:
        mapController.zoomOut();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

I tryed but can't get a location from a address which was entered by user!
I need you help!

Comment: I don't use getfromlocationnam method, i use parse json to get a location which was entered by a user!

Answer (score 0):

```
How to find a location on Map from a address which was be input by user?
```

Using Android **Geocoder** class,

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> listAddress;
GeoPoint geoPoint;
try {
    listAddress = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(userAddress,1);
    if (listAddress == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = listAddress.get(0);
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                      (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

Comment: So I do, but getFromLocationName("user enter a address",1) method do not work! Log cat output : Service not avaiable :(

Comment: I tryed, but not! debug receive the message:"java.io.IOException: Service not Available"

Comment: I can't post my code because I can't enough reputation, Can you post your code for me to consult

Comment: Your code is works fine in my case... Google API 2.2.. Have your add  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in application tag in manifest file. Also    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>?

Comment: My project doesn't contain anything more then which you mentioned in your code. Even class name are same.. Just add your Android Manifest file with question..

Comment: yes, i have.Above the Lines add to AndroidManifest.xml of me But not work

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mappingDemo.html